# Find Closest H3 Value on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I would like to pull the value of the H3 that is closest to the link that is clicked (above the link, not below).

Here is what I currently have:

```
function () { return $(this).closest('h3').find('.singleDownload').text(); }
```

This is not working. I am trying to put this into my Google Tag Manager.

Here is a screenshot of the code:
[image: code]

Comment: `.closest()` only looks at the element itself and its parents. Not siblings or parents siblings. You'll have to me more precise about where your `h3` is located.

Comment: from the docs: closest only searches _up through its ancestors_

Comment: Please provide the actual HTML and not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, `.closest()` only looks at the element itself and its parents. Not siblings or parents siblings.

In your case, you'll have to locate your `h3` more precisely :

```
function () { return $(this).closest('.collapse').prev().find('h3').text(); }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The link is in a div called .collapse, as we have in the code. The H3 I am looking for is in an "<a>" element above the div. Does this change the code you provided? Would it be "prev('a')"?

Comment: @Brian My code should work just fine. `.prev()` selects the previous element.

Comment: Ok. I am a newbie to JS/Jquery. Where in the code does it refer to the click action of ".singleDownload"? Is that the "$(this)" part?

Comment: @Brian I don't know the framework you're using. But in pure jQuery, just do `$(document).on('click','.singleDownload', function(){ ... })`

Comment: That helps! So something like this?

`$(document).on('click', '.singleDownload', function() {
         return $(this).closest('.collapse').prev().find('h3').text();
      }`

Comment: @Brian Again, I don't know what you want to do with the text returned, here, I don't think returning it will do much.

Comment: Sorry. I am creating a JS variable in Google Tag Manager with the value of the "return".

Comment: @Brian Then set your variable to the correct value inside the click handler : `yourVar = $(this).closest('.collapse').prev().find('h3').text();`

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` will find the closest *ancestor* but the element you want, judging from the way the HTML is indented in your screenshot, is not an ancestor of your link. You need to traverse your way up the DOM to an element that is a parent of the H3 you're trying to find.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/